# How I can fetch grant count of the replies

Tags: mysql, count

I am working on comments, I have to display count of the replies while listing of the comments
replies is nth level like

```
parent
       ->child
            -> child
                -> child
Parent
      -> child
      ->child
          ->child
```

My Sql is :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comment` (
  `comment_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'This is primary key of the table',  
  `parent_comment_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL, 
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;



INSERT INTO `comment` (`comment_id`, parent_comment_id`, `text`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'Parent'),
(2, 1, 'child'),
(3,  2, 'child'),
(4,  3, 'child'),
(5,  1, 'child2'),
(6, 0, 'Parent2'),
(7,  6,'child of parent2');
```

Please help me out how i can fetch count of the replies.

Comment: hint: this is a typical model solution for nested sets, google for "nested sets sql"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM `comment` WHERE parent_comment_id = :id
```

will give you the number of replies to comment `:id`. If you need the number of comments in an entire thread, you need to execute this query multiple times, passing in different values for `:id`. Alternatively, you could use [Nested Sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) to store parent-child relationships.